# rewrite timthumb to actual url

Tags: image, redirect, timthumb

I'm stuck.

I don't want to use timthumb anymore and removed it. I get some requests from Facebook that I want to redirect/rewrite with .htaccess, but everything I tried didn't work out.

This is the request url

```
example.com/wp-content/themes/Example/timthumb.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fimage_level1.jpg&h=350&w=960&zc=1
```

and I want them to go straight to

```
example.com/wp-content/uploads/image_level1.jpg
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up using this one

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^src=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F(.*)&h=350&w=960&zc=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/%1? [NC, L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wp-content/themes/Example/timthumb.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F([a-zA-Z0-9]+).jpg&h=350&w=960&zc=1$ wp-content/uploads/$1.jpg
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Charlie, but I still get a 404. The htaccess has only the standard WP lines in it and the code above.

Comment: hmm, I'm guessing the example.com/wp-content/uploads/yourImage.jpg works fine by itself

Comment: Yes. That's the annoying part of it.

Comment: I honestly just hit myself, I believe it might be because you have an underscore in your file name. I didn't account for that in the regular expression, replace ([a-zA-Z0-9]+) with ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)

Comment: Could it be that some of the characters need to be escaped? Like the ampersand?

Comment: Tried it, but still no luck. Maybe I should check with a simple version of the timthumb url first to see if that one redirects.

Comment: you have a good point, I wasn't sure if rewrite rules need to be fully url encoded but an ampersand is %26 if that helps

Comment: Also no luck with this
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wp-content/themes/Example/timthumb.php?src=http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).jpg$ wp-content/uploads/$1.jpg